# How do I return data presorted after grabbing them inside a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

First, I'm grabbing ClientID.  Then, I get all Invoices associated with that ClientID.  I want to return data all ordered by InvoiceNumber, descending.  Here's my code:

```
var rvInvoices =
             (from i in db.QB_INVOICES_HEADER
                where i.ClientID == cId
                select i).ToList();
foreach (var itm in rvInvoices)
{
        InvoiceModel cm = new InvoiceModel()
        {
                InvoiceNumber = itm.InvoiceNumber,
                InvoiceSentDt = itm.InvoiceSentDt,
                InvoiceDt = itm.InvoiceDt,
                Amount = itm.Amount,
                Term = itm.Term,
                ClientName = itm.CI_CLIENTLIST.ClientName
        };

        listInvoices.Add(cm);
}

return listInvoices;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the order in three places.

1. In the initial query,
2. In the `foreach`, or
3. In the `return`

Option 1:

```
var rvInvoices =
    (from i in db.QB_INVOICES_HEADER
    where i.ClientID == cId
    select i).OrderByDescending(i => i.InvoiceNumber).ToList();
```

Option 2:

`foreach (var itm in rvInvoices.OrderByDescending(i => i.InvoiceNumber))`

Option 3:

`return listInvoices.OrderByDescending(i => i.InvoiceNumber).ToList();`

I would suggest taking route 1 since it will run the order at the database level.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try the first method.

Answer (score 2):

```
listInvoices.OrderByDescending(x => x.InvoiceNumber).ToList()
```

Comment: Why sort in memory when you could have it sorted in the DB?  It's usually better at such things.

Comment: What Servy said. Take a look at the other answers on this page.

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like this:

```
var rvInvoices =
               (from i in db.QB_INVOICES_HEADER
                where i.ClientID == cId
                select i).OrderByDescending(x => x.InvoiceNumber);
```

And I don't see a reason you need to call `.ToList()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should order them on the database instead of the client:

```
var rvInvoices = db.QB_INVOICES_HEADER
    .Where(i => i.ClientID == cId)
    .OrderByDescending(i => i.InvoiceNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you currently have creates multiple lists, has an explicit `foreach` loop, and needs to have its output sorted. It can be done with just creating a single list, no explicit looping, and with the database doing the sorting for you:

```
return
    (from i in db.QB_INVOICES_HEADER
     where i.ClientID == cId
     // have the database do the sorting
     orderby i.InvoiceNumber descending
     select i)
     // break out of the DB query to make InvoiceModel
    .ToEnumerable()
    .Select(itm => new InvoiceModel()
    {
        InvoiceNumber = itm.InvoiceNumber,
        InvoiceSentDt = itm.InvoiceSentDt,
        InvoiceDt = itm.InvoiceDt,
        Amount = itm.Amount,
        Term = itm.Term,
        ClientName = itm.CI_CLIENTLIST.ClientName
    })
     // only create one list as the last step
    .ToList();
```